# PyroCMS get the real filesystem path of a uploaded file

Tags: pyrocms

How do I get the "real path" (server path) of a file uploaded to the PyroCMS files module.
I need to get the absolute path such as;

`"c:\www\pyro\uploads\MYSITE_REF\real_file_name.xlsx"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can simply define a constant like this in constant.php

```
define('CUSTOM_FILE_PATH',FCPATH.'/uploads/'.SITE_REF.'/files/');
```

Than you can call it anywhere

```
$local_file = CUSTOM_FILE_PATH. $my_file_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

After much searching around, I couldnt find a solid answer, I did find some global variables that seemed to work.

```
$local_file = FCPATH.'/uploads/'.SITE_REF.'/files/' . $my_file_name;
```

If anyone has a better way of retrieving this please post it :)